# How to make opera mini not cache css?

Tags: javascript, css, opera, opera-mini, opera-mobile

Iphone 5, IOS 7.1, opera mini accepts changes only on first load, i.e. on consequent ones it just ingores any change (css, js, html). In order to see the change I just remove it and install it again and it shows the actual change. WTF? Im aware of the way opera mini transfers its html to its servers and sends back a solid image but this type of behaviour is a overkill. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why would your CSS be changing in a production situation?

Answer (score 1):

Try entering the following in the URL field (without http:// or anything):

```
server:refresh
```

There are a whole bunch more [useful shortcuts](http://looks.wapka.mobi/site_361.xhtml) worth learning, especially for devs.

Answer (score 0):

Use some script to find if it is opera mini and append a random number to stylesheet link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css?r=234234234324234"></link>
```

The above makes opera mini not cache the css

Comment: Get param can be removed, better `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/version_number_here/styles.css"></link>` and add rewrite rules to your web server(apach/nginx/any_other) to redirect such links to `styles.css?v=version_number_here`